# Print the name of a variable

Tags: scheme, r6rs

Is it possible in Scheme R6RS to print the name of a variable? I mean:

```
(define (f) 
   (lambda (arg)
      (display ( *name* arg))))
```

Such that:

```
(define my-var 3)
(f my-var) ; => displays the string "my-var")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a syntactic extension (a.k.a. macro) to prevent evaluation:

```
#lang r6rs
(import (rnrs))

(define-syntax f
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ x) (display 'x)]))

(define my-var 3)
(f my-var)
```

outputs

```
my-var
```

Racket's macro-expander shows the effects of the transformation:

```
(module anonymous-module r6rs
  (#%module-begin
   (import (rnrs))
   (define-syntax f (syntax-rules () [(_ x) (display 'x)]))
   (define my-var 3)
   (f my-var)))

->  [Macro transformation]

(module anonymous-module r6rs
  (#%module-begin
   (import (rnrs))
   (define-syntax f (syntax-rules () [(_ x) (display 'x)]))
   (define my-var 3)
   (display 'my-var)))
```

which, of course, means that you could simply write

```
(display 'my-var)
```

to get the same result ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see how the expression `(f my-var)` is evaluated.
First, note that is an application. Applications evaluate all sub-expressions in some order (in standard Scheme it is undefined, but most Scheme implementation use left-to-right). That is the expression f is evaluated giving a value v1 representing `(lambda () (lambda (arg) (display (*name* arg)))`. The `my-var` is evaluated giving the value `3`. Now `v1` is applied to `3`.

So the problem here is that the function never sees the variable name `my-var`, it only sees the result of evaluating it, `3`.

The answer to your question must therefore be "no".

But it might that there is an alternative solution.
What did you need it for - debugging?